# I'm only getting one color don't know why despite changing color name

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to change the color but it's stuck at one color. It's didn't happen before.

ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=color, fill="cyan"))+geom_bar()

Anyone know why it's happening?

Thank you!

Comment: move the  `fill="cyan"` outside of the `aes`

Answer (score 0):

that's because you choosing one specific color to fill everything ("cyan"). Try using a categorical value instead, like this:

```
ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=color, fill=cut))+
geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

There a fundamental difference between the structure `geom_*(aes(), fill = ...)` and `geom_*(aes(fill = ...))`. In the second case, `fill` will change according to "categories" specified in `...`.

See the example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Species, fill = "any text")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("any text" = "cyan"))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Species), fill = "cyan")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

For more realistic use, please read the example below:

```r
# A more realistic example:
ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(
    "setosa" = "green", "versicolor" = "cyan", "virginica" = "red"
  ))
```